# Extending root partition of RHEL running on vSphere 5.1

Tags: redhat, partition, vmware-vsphere

I need to extend the root (/) partition of a RHEL linux. I know I can do this without too much difficulty by booting in rescue mode. The problem is : the RHEL is a virtual machine running in vSphere ESXi 5.1 environment. I thought I could easily mount a image of the installation cd  in the virtual CD/DVD drive and boot in rescue mode from there, but I can't get it to boot from the cd. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the trick to get the system to boot from your rescue .ISO...

- Check the option to "Force BIOS setup".
- Enter BIOS and choose set the boot order (using the `+` sign).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turns out I was not using the right image and I can not obtain the right one, so I'll have to find another way to resize the root partition, but I was able to boot from the image I had. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I used the Parted Magic distribution image, booted from CD and was able to resize the root partition easily. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't get to boot from the cd due to the boot process going so fast that it doesn't give you the chance to press the keys needed to enter to BIOS mode - there is a trick to delay that. In the .vmx file for the VM add the following entry. Replace the "boot delay in milliseconds" by a number -

```
    bios.bootDelay = “boot delay in milliseconds”
```

In addition to this make sure the ISO is connected to the VM and the checkbox `connect at power on` is selected.